# Vim открытие нового файла

Tags: vim

Я когда заканчиваю редактирование файла, для открытия/создание нового выхожу из vim, и захожу снова. Наверное, есть более гуманный способ, подскажите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делается это так:

```
:e filename
```

Либо:

```
:new filename
```

Первый результат запроса в гугле:
https://ru.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Vim#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BA.D1.80.D1.8B.D1.82.D1.8C.2F.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.8C_.D1.84.D0.B0.D0.B9.D0.BB

Comment: Простите, не было доступа к vim, проверять было некогда, спасибо.

Comment: Не за что извиняться, есть вопрос - есть ответ

Comment: @ZX-SPECTRUM Должно прмгодится - https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree